# Database Construction

Tags: database-design

I am building my first SQL database for work. I want to be able to run queries that show what stocks a particular client owns. I have a table for clients which has an identifier for each portfolio each client manages. Each client may manage multiple portfolios, so I have a column for portfolio_1, portfolio_2, etc. Multiple clients may also be associated with the same portfolio.

In a separate table, I have the list of portfolio identifiers with details about each portfolio. I then have a holdings table to which I plan to upload every holding for each portfolio by ticker. Each holding will have the portfolio identifier and the date of record for the holding. The same holdings will appear multiple times, each with the associated portfolio identifier.

Is this the best way to structure the database? My concern is that it seems simple if each client only managed one portfolio. However, how would I query the database to make sure it found all the holdings in each portfolio the client manages?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: "*I have a column for portfolio_1, portfolio_2, etc.*" - columns with the same name but with numbers at the end almost always indicate a poor design. That typically should be a one-to-many relationship (e.g. `portfolio`, `client` and a table that combines those two, e.g. `client_portfolio`)

Comment: So, if I've got this straight, you have clients. You have portfolios. Each client can have many portfolios and each portfolio can have many clients? Each portfolio may be made up of a range of holdings (or tickers - or what the public would call "shares")? Each holding is made up of many tickers and each holding can be in many portfolios? Sounds to me like you need two joining tables - client->portfolio and portfolio->ticker/share? Is this making sense? My understanding is that a holding is a suite of shares/tickers and a portfolio is a suite of holdings?

Comment: It seems to me that you want a client table, a ticker (share) table, porfolio table and a holding table. Then you have a client_portfolio [joining table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) (JT), a holding_ticker JT and a portfolio_holding JT - all with the relevant `FOREIGN KEY`s. Any reasonable modern RDBMS will be able to cope with this. What RDBMS does your company use or have you decided yet?

Comment: Your columns portfolio_1, etc violates 1NF with an anti-pattern known as repeating groups. Think about how painful this will be when you need to allow for more portfolios, you have to add more columns to the table and adjust every query that uses them.